# CR6-SE issues after a year and ~15 kg of PLA

Tags: print-quality, extrusion, creality-cr-6

I've had a CR6-SE for just over a year now and am not new to 3D printing. However, prior to this I had access to a pretty much brand new Ultimaker S5.

When my CR6-SE arrived, it was essentially plug and play. Therefore I don't have enough experience to be able to diagnose likely causes by looking at the output.

I've used the same branded PLA for the best part of a year, the black worked fine, the green worked fine (probably about 7 kg between those two), although printing at 0.28 mm layer height only ever worked with the PLA that came with the machine and a brand I have since forgotten the name of. I then switched to grey and would have print failures but only on LARGE prints (50 plus hours), and they were all layer adhesion issues. I moved the printer into a cupboard and bumped up the temperatures, but still got layer adhesion issues and a lot of weird looking layer lines. I tightened the belts and it helped a bit but still present with he gray filament.

I then got some turquoise filament and couldn't get anything to print at all with that. I initially assumed it was just something with the colouring altering the properties so got another reel of green. Same issues. Nothing would print.

I dismantled the hot end and found a huge clog, so cleaned that out, but still no successful prints (looked like it was really under extruding on the first layer) then I dismantled the extruder itself. There is some wear on the gear that extrudes the filament, but after rebuilding and tightening it up the quality of the prints is still well off what I was getting 2 weeks ago.

I've done the auto bed levelling and put a new nozzle on it.

I've messed with temp settings, from 200-220 °C and flow rate from 100 to 120 %.

Due to the time taken to change a setting and see the results, this is a very length process so I would greatly appreciate someone with more experience being able to point me in the right direction.

Attached are some photos of last nights job and the start of this mornings job before I came into work.

[image: Completed print showing layer adhesion issues]

[image: Completed print showing top layer adhesion issue]

[image: First few layers as I left this morning 1]

[image: First few layers as I left this morning 2]

[image: Completed print showing top layer not being filled in completely]

Comment: You have a serious under extrusion problem, please look at the extruder and report that in your question. E.g. is the extruder skipping, lever broken?

Comment: could be snags on the spool, they look like that anyway. That situation would also make it very hard to diagnose by working on or tweaking the printer itself, which you've seemed to experienced.